Microsoft Word keeps reverting the proofing language of non-English quotations to English
I am writing a commentary on a French publication.  My own text is English, but I have a lot of quotations in French, and occasional quotations from German, Greek, and Latin texts.  I carefully "Change Proofing Language For (selected text)" in the standard way.  At the end of a work session, I close the document.  When I open it again, some random assortment of the non-English quotations are flagged as misspelled, and sure enough their proofing languages have reverted to English.

After changing the proofing language, if you click on another part of the doc and then click back on the text where you have changed the proofing language, does it say the proofing language on the bottom right of the status bar?  I sometimes suffer from the opposite - it switches to other languages when I want it to stay in English.

Try to turn off the option to "Detect language automatically" at pane Review > Language > Set Proofing Language.

If using character styles still gives the same problem, consider preparing a sample document that has the problem and saving it on OneDrive or DropBox and posting a share link here. You can add it to your post, but if you do, please also comment that you have added it.

Use character styles to firm up your proofing language choice
As Harrymc has advised, turn off the option to "Detect Language automatically."
Here is a link to my article on using character styles for you proofing language choice other than your base language. The article discusses the use of such a style and how to create one manually as well as providing macros to create such a style and a keyboard shortcut.
Here is a macro shown in that article to create such a character style for French.

Sub FrenchLanguageCharacterStyleCreate()  ' SEE ALSO ASSIGNSHORTCUTFRENCHLANGUAGE FOLLOWING
    ' Charles Kenyon
    ' Creates a character style named "French Language" in the Active Document
    ' Does NOT apply the style to a selection, simply creates the style
    ' 18 March 2024
    ' Language IDs [https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdlanguageid][2]

    '
    Dim stlFrench As Style
    '
    On Error GoTo ErrorAlreadyExists
    ' If doing something other than French, change the style name and the languageID throughout this macro
    Set stlFrench = ActiveDocument.Styles.Add(Name:="French Language", Type:=wdStyleTypeCharacter)
    On Error GoTo -1
    With stlFrench
        .Font.Name = ""
        .LanguageID = wdFrench
    End With
    GoTo ExitSub
ErrorAlreadyExists:
    MsgBox Prompt:="Style 'French Language' already exists", Buttons:=vbInformation, title:="Not Needed"
ExitSub:
    Set stlFrench = Nothing
End Sub
Sub AssignShortcutFrenchLanguage()
    '
    ' Charles Kenyon ---- GOES WITH PREVIOUS MACRO
    ' 26 October 2021
    ' Assigns keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Shift+Alt+F to French Language style
    '   Style must exist
    '   Saves this shortcut in the active document
    '
    CustomizationContext = ActiveDocument    ' Change ActiveDocument to NormalTemplate if style is in Normal Template
    '   Change the wdKeyF to appropriate key if changing and use the style name used in the macro above for Command
    KeyBindings.Add KeyCode:=BuildKeyCode(wdKeyF, wdKeyControl, _
                                          wdKeyShift, wdKeyAlt), _
                                          KeyCategory:=wdKeyCategoryStyle, _
                                          Command:="French Language" ' Note, this must be the same name assigned in first macro.
End Sub

See: Instructions for Installing Macros from Forums or Websites
by Graham Mayor, MVP

